# PHP OOP: value property is guaranteed different?

Tags: object-oriented, php

Imagine this code:

```
class Test
{
    public $result;

    public function makeSum($a,$b)
    {
        $sum = $a+$b;
        $this->result = $sum;
    }

}
```

In a webserver.

At **same exact** moment, two browsers call a page that performs that operation. First one has $a=1 and $b=2 and second one $a=5 and `$b=4`.

Are we sure that for first page $result will be 3 and for second one 9? Or is there possibility that result could be "wrong" for the page asking?

I'm talking in particular for PHP, but question can be general...

I think that will be never problems, but I would know if it's true and why.

Thank you!

Comment: yes, the requests are separated so they won't mix at all. If you want to share between requests you need to store the data in a database / file for example. All running code is never mixed. For the same user the session is also an exception, that is also stored in for example a file and shared between your own requests.

Answer (score 1):

They wont mix up. The function runs seperate on each page(browser). Wherever you declared the `$a=1` and `$b=2` will provide: 3. Same for the `$a=5` and `$b=4` will provide: 9. So you dont have to worry about that.